# Loop for a cursor - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on analyzing huge set of data over a year. The approach is to pick the data one day at a time with the help of a cursor and keep on feeding another table with whole year data :-

```
declare
  i_start_date  date := date '2019-04-01';
  i_end_date    date := date '2019-04-02';
begin  
  for cur_r in (select a.id, b.status
                from table1 a join table2 b on a.msg_id = b.msg_id
                where b.t_date between i_start_date and i_end_date
               )
  loop
    insert into test_table (id, status)
      values (cur_r.id, cur_r.status);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Could you please help me run this cursor in a PL/SQL block for the whole year with error handling (e.g:- if data is already there for Apr 01 it should not be inserted again in the table creating no duplicates)

Something like below:-

```
declare
  i_start_date  date := date '2019-01-01'; --start date set
  i_end_date    date := date '2019-12-31'; --end date set
begin

for i_start_date<=i_end_date --condition to fetch data & insert
  (for cur_r in (select a.id, b.status
                from table1 a join table2 b on a.msg_id = b.msg_id
                where b.t_date = i_start_date
               )
  loop
    insert into test_table (id, status)
      values (cur_r.id, cur_r.status);
  end loop;)

  i_start_date+1 -- increment start date


end;
/
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even need pl/sql?

```
insert into test_table (id, 
                        status
                        )
      values (select a.id, 
                     b.status
              from table1 a 
              join table2 b on a.msg_id = b.msg_id
              where b.t_date between date '2019-04-01
                                 and date '2019-04-02'
                and b.t_date not in (select t_date
                                     from status)
;
```

But  beware in your comparison of DATEs (which I have simply replicated) that oracle DATE always includes a time component, and the above comparison will truncate your supplied dates to midnight.  Thus, a row with b.t_date = to_date('2019-04-02 09:10:11','yyyy-mm-dd') will not be selected.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We do need PL/SQL cause of huge data count. We have to recursively fetch and load the data for 1 year - one day at a time.

Comment: A 'huge data count' does not demand PL/SQL.  I regularly insert over a milliion rows into a table with a simple INSERT INTO .. SELECT statement.  Why do you have to 'recursively fetch and load the data for 1 year - one day at a time'?

Comment: We are using dbvisualizer. I tried inserting a week's data but ended up getting this error after 45 mins:-  [Error Code: 1555, SQL State: 72000]  ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 29 with name "-------$" too small

Comment: Did you mean to leave the `values()` part in - seems like you're mixing up the syntax? Also re. your date warning; a bigger issue might be that a value with the time at exactly midnight would be picked up on two runs, since `between` is inclusive.

Comment: As of 0RA-01555: do you, by any chance, COMMIT within the loop? If so, don't do that and you might avoid the error which means that simple INSERT Ed suggested actually does the job.

Comment: I have no experience with dbvisualizer, but in general your looping approach actually exacerbates the problem.  Partly as noted by Alex, commit inside a loop is a prime reason for ora-1555.  Also, looping 'row-by-row' is aka 'slow-by-slow'.  Oracle is _designed_ to work with sets, and when you make a 'set' to be a single row, then you are "row-ing" upstream.  I'd recommend you ditch the loops, go to the straight SQL, and deal directly with any issues there, rather than try to end-run around them.

Comment: @AlexPoole - good catch.  I was just writing code off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Primary Key with the date value you can handle the exception with dup_val_on_index and then use a return.

```
BEGIN
  ...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
     ...
     RETURN;
END;
```

Or you can use a [MERGE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement) to command when to insert or not.

```
MERGE INTO TEST_TABLE T
  USING CUR_R C
  ON (C.DATE = T.DATE)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, status)
  values (cur_r.id, cur_r.status);
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have edited the main question for more clarity on my requirement.

Comment: Hello! If the problem is with a datetime format then you can use TRUNC(Date) to obtain just the date part.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `insert into <table> select ...` statement as

```
SQL> insert into test_table
     select a.id, b.status
       from table1 a
       join table2 b
         on a.msg_id = b.msg_id
      where b.t_date >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' year
        and not exists ( select 0 from test_table t where t.id = a.id );

SQL> commit;
```

through use of `b.t_date >= trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' year` starting from the one year before to the current day.

If you need to start with a certain date such as `date'2019-04-01'` and scan for upcoming one year period,

then use `b.t_date  between date'2019-04-01' and date'2019-04-01' + interval '1' year - 1`

and exclude the already existing data within the `test_table` through

`not exists ( select 0 from test_table t where t.id = a.id )` considering those id columns are unique or primary keys in their respective tables.