# PL/SQL Block Issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to fetch data in chunks and insert in a table for a business requirement.

```
declare
  i_start_date  date := date '2019-01-01'; --start date set
  i_end_date    date := date '2019-12-31'; --end date set
begin

for i_start_date<=i_end_date --condition to fetch data & insert
  (for cur_r in (select a.id, b.status
                from table1 a join table2 b on a.msg_id = b.msg_id
                where b.t_date = i_start_date
               )
  loop
    insert into test_table (id, status)
      values (cur_r.id, cur_r.status);
  end loop;)

  i_start_date+1 -- increment start date


end;
/
```

Could you please help me fix the above block?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you actively making the insert slower and less scalable?

Comment: We are doing some manual analysis in chunks.As such we are not inserting for a year in one go.

Comment: @RLearner seriously; why aren't you doing this in a single insert statement? Is it because you don't have enough UNDO tablespace or something?

Comment: This looks like just a reiteration of your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494115/loop-for-a-cursor-pl-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some issues with your code.

1. for instead of while
2. using a for loop to do single inserts instead of bulk insert
3. Increment +1 wrong
4. Other syntactical errors

So your code should work better (untested) when changing to

```
declare
    i_start_date  date := date '2019-01-01'; --start date set
    i_end_date    date := date '2019-12-31'; --end date set
begin

    while i_start_date<=i_end_date --condition to fetch data & insert
    loop
        insert into test_table (id, status)
        select a.id, b.status
        from table1 a 
        join table2 b on a.msg_id = b.msg_id
        where b.t_date = i_start_date;
        i_start_date := i_start_date+1; -- increment start date
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Probably you should read the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/index.html or try some tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for the help. As a newbie I definitely need some hands on.The resource you shared is helpful.